# Locale defined in parameters.yml is not used

Tags: symfony, locale, fosuserbundle

I've overrided the layout of the FOSUserBundle login screen by creating my own layout.html.twig in the folder of my Bundle. My Bundle is a child of FOSUserBundle.
However, I cannot change the locale, the language is locked in english.

In my parameters.yml, I defined my locale value :

```
# app/config/parameters.yml
parameters:
locale:                 fr
```

Translation is also configured :

```
# app/config/config.yml
framework:
    #esi:             ~
    translator:      { fallbacks: ["%locale%"] }
    default_locale:  "%locale%"
```

My template is the following :

```
{% extends "::base.html.twig" %}
{% block stylesheets %}
    {{ parent() }}
    {% stylesheets
        'css/login-screen.less'
        filter='less,cssrewrite'
    %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" type="text/css" />
    {% endstylesheets %}
{% endblock %}
{% block body %}
    Locale : {{ app.request.locale }} <br />
    {# Flash message of FosUserBundle #}
    {% for key, message in app.session.flashbag.all() %}
        <div class="alert alert-{{ key }}">
            {{ message|trans({}, 'FOSUserBundle') }}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
    {% block fos_user_content %}
    {% endblock fos_user_content %}
{% endblock %}
```

The value displayed for app.request.locale is still "en".
In the framework config, when I change manually the value of default_locale like this :

```
# app/config/config.yml
framework:
    #esi:             ~
    translator:      { fallbacks: ["%locale%"] }
    default_locale:  fr
```

**It works**, and the value of app.request.locale is "fr".
It's like the value defined in parameters.yml is never taken in account.
Am I missing something ? 
Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is only one possibility, you have second `locale` parameter defined somewhere, maybe in another file (`config.yml`).

Comment: omg, you were right. A little above in my config.yml, I've found an already existing locale parameter set to "en". Should I use it instead ? I've heard parameters.yml is only used for parameters that regularly change.

Comment: It's doesn't matter, IMO you should keep parameters that different on development machine and production one, like db connection, passwords for API's etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot my friend